# Correlation of Target-encoded Categorical Variables vs Kruskal-Wallis and Eta-squared Score

Tags: spearman-rho, kruskal-wallis-test, target-encoders

I have a categorical variable X and continuous numeric target variable T. When I use the kruskal-wallis and the [eta-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size) methods to measure the association between X and T, there is a small association. However, when I apply target encoding on X and then use spearman's correlation, I see a relatively large correlation. I should also add that X has a small number of categories. What is the reason for this difference?